# Connect to Google Talk without giving access to my full Google Account

Tags: 12.10, empathy, google-talk

I would like to use Empathy as a Google Talk client. When I choose to go online, I'm asked to give is-admin@canonical.com (Ubuntu) access to manage my online Photo's, Google Drive, Emails and Videos.

I don't understand why Ubuntu has to have all these permissions on my Google account, does this mean Ubuntu will start syncing my Google account to Ubuntu One?

Can I connect to Google Talk without granting access to my Videos, Emails and Photos to Ubuntu? What do you guys want with all my online things?

Answer (score 4):

Open `System Settings -> Online Accounts`

And add a Jabber account using our Google Credentials.

Google Talk is using Jabber/XMPP so you can add an account in every messenger by just entering `username@gmail.com` as a Jabber/XMPP username.

Add TLS for security.

Comment: That did not work. First I tried it normally, and it just does nothing. I then changed the settings to [Google Talk Help](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48758) by including the server and trying the different checkboxes. It takes a long time and then just gives up.

Comment: I'm normally using gajim and there it works like explained. You could install gajim just to check if it's a problem with the server or if empathy is acting strange.

Answer (score 3):

Pidgin is another alternative that works fine as a Jabber/XMPP account.
I wanted to try Empathy but giving Ubuntu full access to my Google account seems a bit much!

Answer (score 0):

Google has a two factor authentication system. This allows you to then setup individual passwords for any application you chose to use. So, I have separate passwords for each account I use for email IiPad,iPhone,work computer). If any of those passwords are compromised you use your two factor authentication to log into your google account and trash that one account you setup, in your case it will be that one Gtalk account.